# SQL*Plus 8.0600 crashes at the trial of connect to Oracle 10g (10.2040)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus, oracleforms

Background: Oracle Forms - DB migration; 6i to 10g

Hi everyone!

Customer situation:
We want to attemp a DB connection with SQL*Plus 8 to a Oracle 10g DB (standard installation). Unfortunately SQL*Plus always crashes without any error message.

We tried the same scenario with our systems - there was no problem.

Now we are confused. Where should we look first to solve the problem? I have no idea.

Perhaps someone of you..

Thanks in advance,

Arne

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SQL*Plus 8.0.6.

There's a limit on the compatibility and 10g doesn't accept connections from clients that old.
There's a metalink note (207303.1) and 8.0.6 was only supported for connections up to 9iR2

If you can get an 8.1.7 client, that was supported for connecting to servers from Oracle8 to 10gR2. If you just need to connect to a 10gR2 database, go with an [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html)

Comment: Hi Gary,
thank you for your support. The same line-up works on our systems. As I said - we (sure, the customer) wanted to run Oracle Forms 6i with 10g DB. The Database connect in Forms is the same as in SQL*Plus. We need an approach. Where should we start looking?

Answer (score 0):

People have got Forms 6i working against Oracle 10g.

It does need the latest patchset (17 or 18, I believe) for Forms 6i

There are also restrictions regarding the character set for the 10g database (can't be AL32UTF8 - metalink note 236231.1).

Comment: Hi Gary - thanks for your time again. Forms 6i <> 10g should run with patchset 18. But Forms chrashed every time without error message. We thought it should be easier to establish the connection via SQL*Plus (cause its nearly the same) - but it chrashed too. The idea is now to fix the SQL*Plus 8 <> ORA 10g problem first, because we thinkt that (could?should?will? :-) be much easier to fix. But it doesn't. Same problem. Crash without error message.

Comment: Try with the 10g XE Western European edition for the database server. People have got that working. I suspect there is something on the server end that 8.0.6 simply can't cope with.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/htdocs/102xewinsoft.html